# iPhone page one is written.. any simple "how to" to make a button go to another page?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

iPhone page one is written.. as view based app, any simple "how to" to make a new page, and how to get a button to take me there?

Also looking for a "how to" make an info button/page to flip..

Anyone? Thx a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in flip behavior, take a look at the "Utility Application" template in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question as there are many ways to show another view. I suggest you start with the [ViewController Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW24) in order to narrow your question down to the type of view and transition you want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play with navigation between views, I would recommend starting with a navigation-based iPhone project and trying some code like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612747/how-do-i-reset-a-uinavigationcontroller/1616015#1616015) to [How do I reset a UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612747/how-do-i-reset-a-uinavigationcontroller)